# Vue "Computed" Value: Regular Function Works, Stabby Arrow Fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, arrow-functions

When I write the code like this, it works:

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: ["notes"],
    computed: {
      hasNotes() { return this.notes && this.notes.some(x => x); }
    }
};
</script>
```

but when I write it like this, it fails:

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: ["notes"],
    computed: {
      hasNotes : ()=> this.notes && this.notes.some(x => x)
    }
};
</script>
```

... and I don't understand why.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" — You're using an arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm certain this is a dupe of something, but an arrow function uses lexically scoped `this` so `this` doesn't mean what you think it means inside the arrow function.

Comment: `<smack type="forehead" />` Oh yeah... thanks.